# No se muestra en la pagina la informacion del usuario

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Este es mi codigo de una pagina que se encarga de editar la informacion de los usuarios,
el mismo se encarga de mostrar la informacion antigua, para poder cambiarlo por la informacion nueva,

**PROBLEMA**

Cuando hago click en el usuario a editar, los placeholder me aparecen vacios sin informacion alguna, al utilizar el console.log() dentro de la funcion componentDidMount y fetchData, no me detecta nada de informacion,

**Ejemplo**

informacion existente:

Nombre:
pepe

correo:
ejemplo@mail.com

twitter:
@ejemplo

cargo:
Developer

al dar click en editar, toda la informacion aparece en vacio en las entradas expuestas.

```
export default class BadgeEdit extends Component{
    
        state = { 
            loading: true,
            error: null,
            form: {
                firstName:'',
                lastName:'',
                email:'',
                jobTitle:'',
                twitter:''
            }, 
        };

    
    //peticion PUT al servidor
    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();

        //setInterval(this.fetchData, 5000);
    }
    
    //carga de la peticion
    fetchData = async e => {
        this.setState({ loading: true, error: null });

        try {
            console.log(this.props.match.params.badgeId)
            const data = await api.badges.read(this.props.match.params.badgeId);

            this.setState({ loading: false, form: data });

        } catch (error) {
            this.setState({ loading: false, error: error });
        }
    }
    


    handleChange = (e) => {
        //dentro del this.setState llamar al objeto
        //del state

        this.setState({
            form: {
                ...this.state.form,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            }
        });
    }

    //evento PUT
    handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        this.setState({ loading: true, error: null });
        
       
        try {
            await api.badges.update(this.props.match.params.badgeId, this.state.form);
            
            this.setState({ loading:false})
            
            this.props.history.push('/badges');

        } catch (e) {
            this.setState({ loading: false, error: e });   
        }
    }


    render(){

        //return del loader
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <PageLoading />
        }

        
        return(
            <React.Fragment>   
                <div className="BadgeEdit__hero">
                    <img className="BadgeEdit__hero-image img-fluid" 
                         src={header} 
                         alt="Logo"/>
                </div>

                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                            <Badge 
                                firstName={this.state.form.firstName || 'FIRTS_NAME'} 
                                lastName={this.state.form.lastName || 'LAST_NAME'}
                                email={this.state.form.email || 'EMAIL'}
                                Twitter={this.state.form.twitter || 'Twitter'} 
                                jobTitle={this.state.form.jobTitle || 'JOB_TITLE'} 
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-6">
                            <h1>Edit Attendant </h1>
                            <BadgeForm 
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                                formValues={this.state.form}
                                error={this.state.error}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </React.Fragment>
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Si `fetchData` no trae información, entonces hay un problema en la petición API, pon un `console.log(data)` después de `const data = await api.badges.read(this.props.match.params.badgeId);` y confirma si trae o no datos.